# How powerful is modern hardware for complex, intensive 2D graphics?

Tags: 2d, sprites, spritesheet, memory-efficiency, 2.5d

I am embarking on a massive (image quality, file size, high frame count) project. I am still working on the basic engine, but have a big question that I would like answered before I begin testing. (It requires a lot of work to test, and possibly fail and have to recreate all sprite sheets, so an answer can help me save weeks of work if I'm wrong.)

The game is entirely in 2D, with 2.5D view. I want to eventually have 40 animations, which all have to be animated in 8 directions. I want each direction/animation to have its own sprite sheet. This equates to hundreds of spritesheets and thousands of files.

Before the obvious solution "Degrade quality for file size!" I would like to take every step possible to prevent degradation of quality, animation frame count, and image size.

Before my solution, one character was 350MB in ram (LOL!) but that was fixed quickly down to 10-20MB per whole character. That is...if I were to load ALL (40) animations in ALL directions (8). So if I were to load 320 sprite sheets into memory, it was going to be a ridiculously large amount per character in ram.

MY QUESTION IS THIS:

How much (of total sprite sheets) should I have loaded into memory at any given point?

Can I get away with loading ONLY the CURRENT spritesheet (Direction + Animation) into memory? Is modern hardware fast enough to constantly swap textures on the fly?

Players could, at any moment, change direction. This would change the entire spritesheet.
Same for animation. So within a split second, the game would have to load a specific new spritesheet, unload the old one (or unload it eventually), and render all within a split second. This would have to be done once for every character, anytime they animate or change directions in a real time game.

Fortunately, the amount of characters on screen at once will be limited by the fact the game is 2D, but I'd prefer to be able to cram in the maximum amount without performance issues on a mediocre computer.

Is texture swapping, file loading, instant rendering from HDD and memory-- all so fast with modern hardware that I wont even need to worry about ANY of this?

I just dont want to work on all of these spritesheets (from thousands of images I already have) only to find out my performance will be horrible and have to redo all spritesheets. Even to test, since I have a layering equipment system, is a time consuming task for spritesheet creation. That is, until I find a solution to process those faster (automation, i do it manually currently, using a program)

Comment: You're talking about using gigs of ram to hold the animations of one **2D** character? Yes your performance will be horrible. Even a modern bleeding edge computer is going to choke. I'm not sure what the point is either, you're going to be loading pixel information for far more pixels than a user could even display. Why load 10,000 pixels for a sprite that is only going to be displayed on 50 pixels of screen space? Beyond that, this question is overly broad and depends on far too many variables to be accurately answered.

Comment: If you really wanted to go hog wild with it you can look into sparse virtual texturing (sometimes also called megatexturing) http://silverspaceship.com/src/svt/  But it's likely that you don't need to go that far.

Comment: No, I am NOT talking about using gigs of ram to hold aniamtions of one 2D character. I am talking about what created my concern (gigs of ram) before finding a possible solution (cutting it down to only 10-20MB per whole character) but with it comes some drawbacks (depending on how fast computations can calculate spritesheet creation).

My first question is in a 2D game, such as Diablo 2 or Baldurs Gate 2, or a 2D or 2.5D game, how many spritesheets or animations are typically loaded into memory per character? All of them? Only the current? Only a few (Current + Last few)?

Comment: Have you tried severing your character's head, arms, body, legs into individual parts? Individual parts will pack tighter into spritesheets and may allow sharing of parts over animations.

Comment: If it takes so much to test it, you are likely doing the wrong test.

Comment: @user15858: "My first question is in a 2D game, such as Diablo 2 or Baldurs Gate 2, or a 2D or 2.5D game, how many spritesheets or animations are typically loaded into memory per character?" All of them. Each character only had one "sprite sheet" (the concept of having more than one was meaningless since they were directly addressing GPU memory). They also rendered at 640x480 or 800x600.

Comment: Individual parts is actually the biggest problem in memory. A single part (a single character sprite) is about 1-3MB in memory with all my animations it cannot possibly exceed 20MB for a single character. If I were to NOT compound all the paperdoll technique (layers of images for equipables) and do them in pieces, that is what would exceed 350MB per character. I have to either not load so much in memory, or have the game create compounded spritesheets on load from a series of layered images. My only fear is that this will be too slow to allow fast equip/unequip actions.

Comment: A single equip requires it to compound thousands of images again to form the new character sprite.

I think though this isn't a problem because texture swapping is handled quick enough to allow for only required spritesheets to be loaded in memory. The rest stay on the HDD.

Answer (score 5):

Swapping textures will kill your performance.  Modern hardware has only gotten more susceptible to this problem, not less, as the speed and power of the shader units and video RAM are growing much faster than the speed increases of the bus between system RAM and the GPU.

The only sane approach is to cut down your texture sizes, or generate procedural sprites (using vector art).  As another reply stated, there is absolutely zero reason to have huge textures for sprites that will only be a few dozen pixels tall on the output.  It sounds like you're looking for a solution to a problem that you're imposing on yourself for no reason.

Also, you will usually have better looking art if you design for the target pixel size than if you downscale a high-res texture.

Comment: Indeed - *"It sounds like you're looking for a solution to a problem that you're imposing on yourself for no reason"*

Comment: "As another reply stated, there is absolutely zero reason to have huge textures for sprites that will only be a few dozen pixels tall on the output."

Zero reason to have spritesheets as opposed to tiny single images? This is contrary to what I read on here about spritesheets vs single images. (Always load a huge image than to load a lot of tiny ones).

Comment: Any "problem" I impose on myself is obviously for a reason, such as a game feature or quality.  If there was no reason, there wouldn't be a problem lol.

Comment: @user15858 If it was easy like this, the AAA 2D games would be like this, dont you think? And no. He wasn't referring to the sprite sheets, he was referring to having ultra HD quality on your images to then scale them down. And also he said texture swapping that is, changing from one spritesheet to other THIS will kill your game. By the way, have you thought about Vector art? you do one size, get a very HD quality with animations as smooth as the CPU can.

Comment: @user15858: of course use sprite sheets.  But your sprite sheets should be able to fit a LOT of sprites on them.  I'm shipping a high-res 2D action game in the next few weeks that only has a dozen 1024x1024 sprite sheets, and it looks great.  There's no reason to have bazillion sprites at large resolutions.

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot or example of one of your sprite sheets or a character (and tell the # of frames of that character in a single sheet).

If I were to make an action game or a smaller game, it wouldnt be a problem even with huge massive sprites. An RPG is a much, much bigger project than a smaller game. Every monster, item, character type, and world object is yet another sprite.

Comment: My sprite sheets do fit a ridiculous number of sprites on them. The frame rate isn't very high, either. It's just a lot of content.

Comment: The frame rate isn't very high, either. It's just a lot of content. It is not a good thing to assume without any evidence that the problem is specific [too high res, too big sprites] and that there is no reason (there is always a reason). Anything can bulk up a sprite sheet, and a developer has to consider what to cut to save performance since there is so many ways to save on performance. Cutting the frame# will obviously will degrade animation. Cutting resolution will prevent zooming or lose detail. A simple change from png to jpg could save HDD space but can make memory worse.

Comment: @user15858: since you're so convinced you don't have a problem with the design of your data, why are you asking for help?  Just ship your game with a ton of spritesheets and test on target hardware to make sure it all works.  If it does, don't worry about it.  Performance will suffer, but if that just means that you go from 350fps to 70fps, who cares?  For the (very old) games you're using as reference, just remember that sprites were tiny, animations were not particularly smooth, and the target graphics hardware were not modern GPUs expected to be running tons of shaders and effects.

Comment: I'm not sure if the performance would be bad or not. I do not know if there is a problem, and although there isn't *IF* I handle it a certain way, there are downsides to handling it that way.

I took some of your advice and did the best I could to shrink the size down to as low as I could without losing any real quality. (It's exactly 70% the original size, and all detail is still visible.) I mostly however decided to take another look at my animation frame count and fps of my animations.

Comment: I tried shrinking the fps from 15 to 6, it was really crappy. Fortunately it actually looks significantly better at 7.5 (every other frame of my 15) than created with 6fps (very strange, but theres a huge difference: 6fps looks choppy, 15fps and only using every odd frame is smooth). I still am sticking with 15fps, but for a more "packed" lower quality version (last poster's suggestion) I might ship with a smaller HDD version that'll be half the HDD space with 7.5fps animations.

Comment: What I did the best was edit my animations to be shorter, without losing much quality. If at worst I can reverse animate everything, making only half the animation of most animations animate. This means instead of a 20 frame animation, it just does the 10 then reverses the animation for 20 frames animated but only 10 used. This makes the animations look less realistic though. In a worst case scenario, I can reduce fps, reverse animate, and even shrink. Best case scenario this works and very little quality is lost.

Either way I think modern hardware can handle it.

Comment: I took my longest animation (Idle) and shrunk it to be shorter than most of my other animations (<20 frames). Most of my animations, in a single direction for a character, is 70-85kb each. 

This is a huge deal for me as although I still can't tell the GPU/RAM performance, I do now know that even with 40 animations, 40 characters, 8 directions, will all only be 1 GB of HDD space. So my game wont be 200GB like I feared. Not even close, as I'll be surprised if it passes 4GB.

Each sheet though still says 3MB in memory in TexturePacker, even if a 80kb JPEG.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the GPU has to constantly swap textures and not store very much in memory. Even with compressed jpegs, in memory the jepgs are uncompressed and so a 80kb file can consume 3MB of memory. Even so a 27kb file would still be 1MB in memory and that would fill up quickly. I'm pretty sure games like Ultima Online or Diablo 2 didn't hold ALL animations in ALL directions in ALL possible characters at once in memory. I'm pretty sure even with CPU graphic acceleration the texture swapping was constant. I dont think swapping textures is a problem, as you dont even *REQUIRE* spritesheets.

Comment: Again, you are comparing ancient low-res games made before GPUs were a thing to the requirements for a modern high-res game.  These things are not the same.  The optimization tricks from even a few years back are often conpletely invalidated on new hardware.  Older games ran on hardware  where the difference between the bus interconnect speed, memory speed, and processing speed were much much smaller than today.

Comment: Older games didn't use OpenGL or modern D3D, didn't store textures in VRAM, and were basically just accelerated blitting engines; this is not at all how modern hardware works.  The acceleration methods used by old games are literally not even in new hardware anymore.  Your question was whether there's be a performance hit doing things the way you describe - the answer is yes, a big one.  Also rememer that modern GPUs do allow compressed textures, which can help a lot.  Look into trying DDS textures instead of JPGs (no game uses JPGs - worst possible texture format for a game).

Comment: You're right, JPG's wont work. I swear I had the alpha color perfected where the artwork looked perfect as JPG's with black as the alpha color, but no matter what I try now, they are outlined with nasty black edges. Whatever I did, I obviously didn't do, and must have dreamt it and confused myself. It was a long time ago when I thought I had successfully used JPG's, but apparently I either lost how or just THOUGHT I did/could. back to PNG for me :(

Comment: DDS Textures are massive, most often worse than the original PNG. The solution was PNG-Quant. The ram and texture swapping was never a problem, it was actually the HDD space that the files would consume. I couldn't have a 200GB game unless I streamed the assets as required. Thx for the help though.

Comment: Just an update- swapping textures did NOT kill performance in any way. The CPU usage is minimal and the framerate doesn't drop at all even when constantly swapping textures.

This user 'Sean Middleditch' was entirely wrong. Modern Hardware is extremely powerful, and can handle nearly anything except perhaps MASSIVE 8192x8192 or higher textures.

Comment: "It works" proves nothing.  Swapping textures means transferring things over the bus.  This _is_ slow; you're just lucky and not stressing it much; common for little hobbyist games.  Doing this in general is bad juju, and that is plain fact.  Modern hardware is plenty "powerful", so longed as it's not abused too hard.  You're only abusing it a little.  :) and yes, disk transfer is a major problem, disk is much slower than anything else; finding the balance between disk and runtime speeds is part of what we get paid to do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prototype this, with placeholder data.

Create a simple program that outputs a sprite sheet where each frame consists of text describing what it should be (e.g. "Sprite 7 frame 5"). Use that to create the final number of sprite sheets you're going to end up with, and see how well that runs a test scene with everything loaded into memory.

If it runs ok on your target hardware then go ahead and create your sprites, otherwise you'll need to adjust your plans or optimize the code to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making the graphics quality configurable in the game.  For example you could set a target for the "high end" of hardware you want your game to work on, and design your graphics and animations around that target.  Then provide graphics quality settings that let you, say, use 50% scaled versions of the sprites, or use every other frame of animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only targetting Windows/Mac/Linux, I wouldn't worry about HDD space.

Some of the most popular AAA titles are 20GB+ or larger.

If it's an online game, a singleplayer RPG, or a MMORPG, you could easily introduce a small client with less content (6-8GB max) and then introduce "expansion packs".

What people don't realize is that some games have a large client of 6+GB, and the expansions grow it to over 20GB.

The key though is to allow accessibility without having to download all 20GB of content. Example, WoW's streaming client vs Vanguard: Saga of Heroes. WoW is actually larger than the 20GB beast of Vanguard, but the former can be played in an hour of downloading on Cable, while the latter can take days for people to download.

Your problem is definitely going to be memory, as HDD space isn't a real requirement, nor are the draw calls for 2D graphics. Your memory problem will occur long, long, long before any HDD space (a virtually non-existent problem in modern streaming tech) or Rendering problems.

Keep the number of characters loaded small. Refrain from excessively large spritesheets. It is better to have a Dragon composed of 4+ sprites (chopped up dragon pieces) or stream single images (no sprite sheet at all for Dragons) than to load massive sheets.

Trying to animate a 4000x4000 sprite sheet dragon will make your game slow. Animating 10, 400x400 sprites will not. As long as your memory usage doesn't explode, your game should have no problem. As a 2D game, I can't imagine that many characters being on screen at any given moment unless the camera is zoomed out. If the camera is zoomed out, perhaps having smaller sprite images for that viewpoint would be better. It would create a ton more HDD space, but would help with memory dramatically.

Also, see about loading RGBA4444 instead of RGBA8888 to keep memory even lower. The former can still result in beautiful sprites.